# Spring MVC - Could not get RequestDispatcher

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I got a problem on my Spring MVC application.

The problem **only** happens on the linux server, on local (windows 7 + eclipse), everything works fine.

When I access my page, **the controller is called** but when the server has to serve the jsp page, i've got :

```
HTTP Status 500 - Could not get RequestDispatcher for [/WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp]: Check that the corresponding file exists within your web application archive!
```

The file exist, the path is fine.

Here an extract from my web.xml

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>cms-admin-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cms-admin-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/do/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/cms-admin-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

and my servlet dispatcher :

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

I tried to replace my /do/* pattern by *.html but there is no change.
I also tried to put my jsp outside WEB-INF.

I tried :

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp</jsp-file>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/toto</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

That works, the jsp page is loaded but not resources.

Other thing, I am unable to access any js file directly (resources/js/logs.js, outside the WEB-INF). I get a 404, on local I get my file.

I have pretty no idea where this is coming from, again, it works perfectly on my local. The tomcat config is pretty common. so thanks for advance for any ideas.

Comment: Have you check the file again. Is it inside WEB-INF/pages?

Comment: May be `index.jsp` is outside the WEB-INF folder directly under the wepapp (war).

Comment: Yes, I checked the file is in the good place. I configure my tomcat for unpacking warfile. So, I can see the file.

For the duplicate, I don't think so, it's seems to be a different problem. I join the controller, the mapping is executed well. But micha's response will potentially help me.

Comment: In linux and windows machines, kindly check forward and backward slashes while mentioning file path. This is a common conflict.

Comment: I don't think this is about slashes, the path and case seems good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 
[Tomcat unable to find jsp in war file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232225/tomcat-unable-to-find-jsp-in-war-file) post give me the problem.

The default web.xml (on the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml) was missing. The result was that default operation and servlet wasn't properly made up.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html

I just added it to the conf folder of my tomcat to fix the problem.