# Spring Boot - ErrorPageFilter cannot find RequestDispatcher

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application running in a stand alone Tomcat container - I have slowly been making progress in getting the global error handling to work (custom 404 pages etc), and the `ErrorPageFilter` class is now catching the error, but it throws a `NullPointerException` trying to forward the request to the `ErrorPage`.

The stack trace is as follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleErrorStatus(ErrorPageFilter.java:141)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:112)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
```

Looking at the source for `ErrorPageFilter` on the version I have, it is failing trying to match the `RequestDispatcher` for the error path:

```
private void handleErrorStatus(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response, int status, String message)
    throws ServletException, IOException {

if (response.isCommitted()) {
    handleCommittedResponse(request, null);
    return;
}

String errorPath = getErrorPath(this.statuses, status);
if (errorPath == null) {
    response.sendError(status, message);
    return;
}
response.setStatus(status);
setErrorAttributes(request, status, message);
request.getRequestDispatcher(errorPath).forward(request, response);
```

(the last line is the NPE)

I have configured my error handling as follows, the error config:

```
@Configuration
class ErrorConfiguration implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Override public void customize( ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container ) {
        container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage( HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "/errors/404" ))
        container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage( HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "/errors/500" ))
    }
}
```

Which seems to be ok - those error pages are registered and the `ErrorPageFilter` is kicking in.

I have tried registering the path "/errors/404" as both a standard view-controller and as a `@Controller` request mapping (also note, if I just go directly to /errors/404 in the browser the url is resolved and the page is displayed)

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an error on my part - was caused because the web.xml was deleted by accident - so the RequestDispatcher was not available.

Adding the web.xml resolved this.

Similar to behaviour:

[Tomcat unable to find jsp in war file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232225/tomcat-unable-to-find-jsp-in-war-file)

[Spring MVC - Could not get RequestDispatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23721942/spring-mvc-could-not-get-requestdispatcher)